# Forcing Windows to free allocated memory

Tags: c++, windows, memory, memory-management, free

I'm dealing with a bit weird scenario here but it is exactly what I planned to create. It's just special kind of testing software...

My environment: MSVS 2012, Windows 7/8 32b/64b.

So, firstly I'm creating some internal structures/buffers/etc to use in my app, then I'm doing something like this (simplified here a bit, please treat it rather like pseudocode):

```
{
   std::deque<boost::scoped_array<unsigned char>> deque;
   try {
     while (1) {
       deque.push_back(boost::scoped_array<unsigned char>(new unsigned char[system_page_size])); // happens to be 4096 on my system
     }
   }
   catch (std::bad_alloc& ex) { ... }
   // do something here
}
```

I need to use as much memory as possible. I'm allocating whole pages at once (maybe that's bad and should leave some space for deque's/smart ptr's data?). When CRT decides that no more allocation is possible, I will do some more stuff (not relying on any memory availability at all) and then will exit the scope. It will trigger chain of destructors and all this data should be freed.

This works great. But I happen to enter this weird scope not once but 10 times in a loop. It sometimes works 2 or 3 times. Sometimes only once. Next time I will get only out of memory errors and that's it.

From my perspective I need to restart the whole process in order to really force memory to be released. Is there a method to achieve this in single process?

I can think of trying different allocators - maybe it's CRT issue? I have also played a bit with heap manipulation (i.e. low fragmentation heap) but didn't help either.

Comment: You're fragmenting the heap. That's normal behavior -- "windows" isn't holding on to memory for you. You could call `VirtualAlloc` directly for this workload though.

Comment: Ok, I'am fragmenting process heap but then I'm trying to allocate exactly the same kind of chunks. I don't see problem here since there are no extra allocations after first bad_alloc is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Why not reserve your process's entire memory space with a few large sized [VirtualAlloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366887%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) calls using MEM_RESERVE. Then you would call VirtualFree later on each memory range to release. This would still require some amount of heap allocation like you are doing here to exhaust the rest of your current heap. It will be faster and remove the page file churn you must be experiencing.

As for your specific problem, I don't know why you are experiencing it. Reserving all of the memory so the heap can't expand should help reduce the non-determinism.

Comment: Is there a good way to _calculate_ size of this few large pages? If I will ask for too much then it will just fail.

Comment: You can map the process's address space by calling [VirtualQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366902%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) until you've exhausted your address space. Then all of the MEM_FREE regions can be reserved with VirtualAlloc. Just query starting with the minimum address and a length extending to the max address. Check GetSystemInfo to get the addressing range.

Comment: I will add if this is multi-threaded, the allocated pages will change so reserve the address as soon as VirtualQuery reports a free range. Save the result pointer for later releasing. You probably want to start by allocating a large array to hold these pointers as STL containers would allocate each on the fly, which may fail as you are exhausting memory.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using LARGE amounts of memory, using some sort of slab-allocation (VirtualAlloc will give you the memory for that) and then, in principle [assuming your the objects created in that block doesn't need the destructor to do something], you could just throw away the entire block in one go, rather than using delete a gazillion times - with the added benefit of saving time as well as guaranteeing that your memory has been completely freed.

I suspect one reason you may have problems is that the freed blocks will have to be cleared before they can be recycled. This is done in a background thread in the kernel. Of course, using VirtualALloc won't actually help on this account.

It is of course also possible that you get memory fragmentation, in which case using a head designed to avoid this would work.